# How to create DOT file and image file using the terminal on Mac

Tags: python, macos, terminal

After entering this using the terminal on a Mac -

```
~ $ python diagram-generator.py -f test.cfg
```

I got -

```
Creating DOT file "test.cfg.txt" ... 
Creating image file "test.cfg.png" ...
```

But it didn't create any dot file or image file. How do you create a proper DOT file and image file using the terminal?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Nobody can answer to that question without knowing what is `diagram-generator.py`

Comment: It's a python code to generate a .png file which can display the diagram based on the .dot file